# Cloud Run Deploy: Error in retrieving repository from Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I used to be a happy user of Cloud Run (and the entire Google Cloud platform, actually). I never had any difficulties deploying my projects and the projects of the companies I worked for on it, especially on Cloud Run, which I'm a big fan of.

For a while, I switched to Amazon AWS and then came back with a new project to the Google Cloud Platform.

I have the `gcloud` authenticated with the project's email that I intend to deploy, and I'm using the latest version of the CLI.

However, when trying to deploy, which has always been straightforward, I receive the error below, both on my local machine and in the cloud, using GitHub Actions.

This command has ALWAYS worked for me like a charm, I never had any issues. However, this time, it gives an error. In the past, when it gave an error, it would suggest what to do, like enabling an API or something similar... I even tried deploying to ANOTHER service that already uses Cloud Run and had the exact same error... This makes absolutely no sense. What am I doing wrong?

```
gcloud run deploy rpc --source . --allow-unauthenticated --platform managed --project my-project
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Error in retrieving repository from Artifact Registry.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Comment: Your problem is probably an old CLI (gcloud) version. Make sure you have updated the Google Cloud SDK CLI. Which version are you using? The current version is 452. If you don't want downvotes, provide all the required information to reproduce your problem. We have no idea which configuration files you are using (contents of Dockerfile), etc.

Comment: I am using the latest (452), installed not using brew, using asdf, I know that is not official, thought. Google ecosystem is SO broken, I always used in this way, always worked.

I am very happy that nowadays I use other cloud providers at my work and not Google anymore.

Comment: I agree that a better error message would be helpful. However, ranting is unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a damn typo in the region, it was wrong. But how can a billion-dollar company, where only the most brilliant minds in the world are capable of solving extremely complex algorithms during a 30-minute interview, not have a damn input validator in place?

Even my side projects has!